# A Few Python questions

Tags: javascript, python

I'm trying to learn Python from a background in javascript. I saw someone make a recursive function to find the least common denominator and wondered why they didn't just use a loop, so, both for the experience and to amuse myself, I wrote a simpler one:

I came up with:

```
def LCM(n,d):
    while(n%d++ != 0 ):
        continue
    return d-1
print(LCM(99,12))
```

Needless to say, for those of you that know Python, ++ isn't a valid operator. I also tried

```
def LCM(n,d):
    while(n%(d+=1) != 0 ):
        continue
    return d-1
print(LCM(99,12))
```

To make sure it wasn't my thinking that was off, I tried the same thing in javascript:

```
function LCM(b,d){
   while(b%d++ != 0){
   }
return d-1;
}
```

So does Python not allow expressions like in javascript? Also, is indentation the only way to define something? I know semicolons aren't required but can be used, is there anything like that in terms of closing a loop or function definition?

Finally, are `is` and `is not` the Python equality-without-type-coersion operator?

P.S. I realize the function isn't practical without checking the input for various things, but that wasn't the point in writing it.

P.P.S Also, is there a Python equivalent of the javascript `evaluation ? on true : on false` if statement abbreviation?

Comment: Well, in this case, it wasn't necessary, but for something like listing file trees, it would be.

Comment: Why? Python is perfectly capable of doing recursion and that is the best solution for some problems.

Comment: @tom-zychThank, thanks. I'd love to hear an explanation of why he thinks that though.

Comment: @Walkerneo By the way, there's nothing wrong with asking multiple questions on stackoverflow for ... multiple questions. That way, it becomes easier to discuss the fine points.

Comment: If you want to know about how Python does coercion, read this http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#coercion-rules

Comment: "So does Python not allow expressions like in javascript"?  How much of a Python tutorial have you done? Which one have you used?  Why didn't the tutorial provide you the information you needed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not allow assignments (such as `i+=1`) in expressions since those can lead to confusing code, and Python is designed to make it hard to write confusing code, and make it simple to write  obvious code.

You can simply write this:

```
def LCM(n,d):
    while n%d != 0:
        d += 1
    return d-1
print(LCM(99,12))
```

Python's `is` tests for two objects being the *same* object instead of just equal. Consider the following:

```
d = {}
e = d
assert d == {}     # Empty dictionaries equal each other
assert d is not {} # .. but are not identical
assert d is e      # d and e refer to the same object
```

There is no equivalent operator to `is` in JavaScript, and there is no equivalent to JavaScript's `==` in Python. Python's `==` does type checking for the built-in types.

The **conditional operator** (`a ? b : c` in JavaScript) is written out in Python as:

```
 b if a else c
```

Comment: Thanks, way to get most of my questions in one go :D. So Python's `==` doesn't allow for type coersion anyway? Also, what about statement closure? Is it only indentation? Also, are semicolons just optional, or are you NOT supposed to use them?

Comment: @Walkerneo Python does no type coercion by default, but you can overwrite the behavior of nearly all operators if you desire to do so. There are no braces (try `from __future__ import braces`) in Python, it's all indentation. Semicolons are a hack for command-line programs and should not occur at all in a Python program.

Comment: `Python does not allow side effects in expressions` - That's bullshit. You can overload unary plus to launch nuclear missles if you wish. It's just that assignment and augmented assignment aren't expressions. Otherwise good and correct answer.

Comment: BTW, the function is wrong.  It return LCM(99,12)=32, but the LCM of 99 and 12 is 396.

Comment: What does ` from __future__ import braces` do? If there's no type coercion, then why does `if(1):` evaluate to true?

Comment: @delnan Yes, that's indeed wrong. One could just call `funcWithSideEffects`. Clarified.

Comment: @Walkerneo: (1) Try it out. See http://docs.python.org/library/__future__.html#module-__future__ for `__future__` in general. (2) Because booleans aren't the only things that have a truth value. Nonzero numbers are considered true. In fact, the booleans are basically the integers 1 and 0 with a prettified string representation. Similarily, collections are false if empty and true otherwise.

Comment: Sorry Mark, I meant it to be least common divisor starting at d. I wasn't thinking at the time of showing anyone else the code, so I didn't think it would matter.

Comment: @Walkerneo Try it out in your Python console, it's a joke. Usually, importing from the `__future__` module allows one to use features of the language not yet enabled by default, for example `from __future__ import print_function` to have Python 3's `print` semantics in, say, Python 2.7. There is no type coercion for *the comparison operators*, but there is type coercion for necessarily boolean values such as the one after `if`.

Comment: @delnan I thought that in programming languages, 1 and 0 being true and false was type coercion. I understand they are in binary, but the integers 1 and 0 don't evaluate to 1 and 0 in binary right?

Comment: @Walkerneo As a historical accident, `bool` is a subclass of `int`. But even if it weren't, type coercion (only to boolean) is performed when a boolean is required.

Comment: @Walkerneo: Well, under the hood `if` does ask the object in question to create a boolean that represents its truth value, and you can do the same conversion explicitly with the `bool` function - I guess it could be thought of as implicit conversion. But conceptually, it's not that the object is being converted to a boolean, it's the object itself having a truth value. (And your remark on binary representation doesn't make sense.)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about that integer and binary comment, I hadn't thought it through. So 1 represents the integer 1 and the value true? Is that why there is no `true` keyword?

Comment: @Walker No, there is a `True` (with a capitaqlized T, for whatever reason), but `True is not 1`. Instead, True is an instance of the class `bool`, which is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: @phihag, thanks, I don't know why I didn't check for a true with a capital t. You're saying that there isn't type coercion, but that `1 is not true`, but `if(1)` is true. Delnan said that it's because the if statement takes the truth value of something; isn't that type coercion?

Comment: @Walkerneo Sorry, I wasn't precise enough. There is no type coercion *for comparison operators like `==` and `>`*.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for semicolons in Python, everything is done with indentation. Also, mixing up tabs and spaces can lead to problems. Stick to one or the other. :)

Comment: That's my fear though. I don't feel comfortable without my semicolons and closing braces.

Comment: @Walkerneo: Then get used to it. It's just aesthetics, and for most even a matter of habit.